# Java Conditional statement (simple enough)

Tags: java, conditional-statements

My program is to tell if a year entered is a leap year that meets these requirements:

A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4. But if the year is divisible by 100, it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400.

Create a program that checks whether the given year is a leap year.

Here are what results should be produced per input:

Type a year: 2011
The year is not a leap year.

Type a year: 2012
The year is a leap year.

Type a year: 1800
The year is not a leap year.

Type a year: 2000
The year is a leap year.

This is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Type a year ");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (number % 4 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println(" This is a leap year");
        } else if (number % 100 == 0 && number % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.println(" This is a leap year ");
        } else {
            System.out.println( "This is not a leap year");
        } 
    }
}
```

All of them work except 1800. 1800 is not a leap year and my program says that it is (it is not divisible by 400). It seems that (number % 100 == 0 && number % 400 == 0) only works if (number % 4 == 0 ) is not there. Why does my program not work correctly?

Comment: Please fix your brackets to make your code more readable!

Comment: Organize your `if` clauses so the largest test (vs. 400 years) is performed first. Otherwise, since 1800 % 4 == 0, it's going to end evaluating in the first part of the `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens when the year 100 is inputted. `100 % 4 ==0` is `TRUE`, so your code outputs that the year is a leap year. The problem is, `100 % 100 == 0` is also `TRUE`, but your code will never reach this line, nor will it check if `100 % 400 == 0` is `TRUE`.

You printed out the result before you checked all of the conditions!

Change the structure of your if else.

This sounds like a homework assignment, so I don't want to give you the answer. You should have all of the information needed to reach it from here. If not, feel free to comment with any questions.

EDIT: Since you appear to have gotten the core of the problem, here is what is wrong with your answer.

Your brackets `{` and `}` are in the wrong places, among other things. Placing your brackets in the locations I do is part of the Java standard, and makes your code easier to read, understand, and debug. (It makes it easier to identify when they are missing as well.)

Your code should look something like this:

```
// Pay attention to a few things here. It checks if it is divisible by 4
// since every leap year must be divisible by 4. If it is,
// it checks if it is divisible by 100. If it is, it must also
// be divisible by 400, or it is not a leap year. So, if it is divisible
// by 100 and NOT divisible by 400, it is not a leap year. If it isn't 
// divisible by 100, control flows to the else statement, and since we
// already tested number % 4 we know it is a leap year.
// Pay special attention to where I located my { and }, this is the 
// standard way to do it in java, it makes your code readable by others.

if(number % 4 == 0) {
    if((number % 100 == 0) && !(number % 400 == 0)) { // NOTE THE ! OPERATOR HERE
        System.out.println("The year is NOT a leap year.");
    } else {
        System.our.println("The year is a leap year.");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("The year is NOT a leap year");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm really just learning Java on my own, and following a course. The lesson didn't really give any information on nested ifs. I read up on them and saw the && operations are similar, but thats about it. I spent alot of time researching this...anyway you can put me out of my misery?

Comment: Ya, I actually just tried that from what I read up on. Let me try it again, and I'll post what I come up with.

Comment: Remember that every number that is divisible by 100 is also divisible by 4; think about what that implies about the order you need to check things in. If you still can't get it, I'll give some more help.

Comment: I posted the answer of what I came up with.

Comment: Cant get anything to print with that statement however.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but you mean Not a leap year for your Else statement right? I'm trying to understand what the ! is used for here. I know it is the negation operation.

Comment: Exactly. Read `!` as NOT. So, if `number % 400 == 0` evaluates to `TRUE`, the `!` operator flips this value to `FALSE`. The statement could be read as if number % 400 == 0 is FALSE. Another way of writing this would be `number % 400 != 0`, read as if number % 400 is not equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry wanted to make sure you caught my edit. You meant not a leap year right? for the else?

Comment: No, the else condition would mean that it IS a leap year. If a number is divisible by 4, it IS a leap year, UNLESS the number is also divisible by 100 AND not divisible by 400.

Comment: Ok, but shouldnt one of the print statements read "This is not a leap year?"

Comment: Oh! I see now! Yes! I forgot a line in my answer. I edited my answer. My code wouldn't have printed out that it was not a leap year if it was not divisible by 4, but I fixed that. See my answer, I revised it. Good catch!

Comment: It's quite late here, my apologies! I fixed my code. You should be able to copy and paste it directly to test it now.

Comment: np, I think I'm understanding. I'm a beginner, and this one was a little above me. Thanks alot for your help. I'll study this more

Comment: If there is an answer that you believe fully answers your question, you can mark that answers as accepted.

Comment: Marked it. The way I read the program is: The computer reads the first line, if the condition is false, it ends up going to the very last else statement, and is printed as not a leap year. If it is true, it proceeds to the next if statement. Correct?

Comment: If the `if` statement is false, the program hands control to the next `else if` statement. If all `else if` statements are false, then control flows to the `else` statement.

Comment: Ok, but in this case here there is no else if correct? So, if the first line is false it doesn't move to the first else, but the last one because of the indent difference? In other words, the last else is the outer else that belongs to the outer if?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bool isLeap = false;
if (number % 4 == 0) {
  isLeap = true;
  if (number % 100 == 0)
    isLeap = false;
  if (number % 400 == 0)
    isLeap = true;
}
if (isLeap) { //print stuff
```

That should work for you. You're preempting your own logic by outputting early.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought that the first statement was preempting me. I didn't learn much about booleans, so I'm not sure if this lesson could be done without them. I was only given information on && || operations.

Comment: Booleans aren't really your issue here; it's the order that you are checking the conditions. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Type a year ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    if (number % 4 == 0 ) 
        if (number % 100 == 0) 
          if (number % 400 == 0)
          {
        System.out.println(" This is a leap year");
    }   else {
        System.out.println( "This is not a leap year");
    } 
}
```

}

Here you go HC. I only cannot get it to print properly. Close?

Comment: Your brackets are wrong. I'll edit my answer to show you what it should look like.